# I can't get localhost:3001/api/notes to display anything

Tags: node.js, json, express, localhost

So my server.js code is as follows:

```
const express = require('express');

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3001;
const app = express();
const { notes } = require('./db/db');

app.get('/api/notes', (req, res) => {
    const result = notes;
    res.json(result);
});

app.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log(`API server now on port ${PORT}!`);
});
```

The db.json file is as follows:

```
[
    {
        "title":"Test",
        "text":"Test"
    }
]
```

After running `npm start` in terminal and going to localhost:3001/api/notes it supposed to show the contents of db.json, but it is just showing a blank page. Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong?

When i replaced `res.json(result)` with `res.send('Hello')` it displayed the "Hello" just fine which leads me to believe there is a problem with connecting db.json to server.js

Help Please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless there is a `notes` property of your `db.json` file there is no need to surround your `notes` variable during its declaration.

**Instead use:**

```js
const notes = require('./db/db');
```

If you use

```js
const { notes } = require('./db/db');
```

Its the same as trying to access the `notes` property of the json file, which youve shown none so I've assumed its blank.

[You can read more on destructuring assignments here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment)

Answer (score -1):

Your problem is in how you import the JSON file. Assuming your JSON file has path `db/db.json`, replace this line:

```
const { notes } = require('./db/db');
```

with this one:

```
const notes = require('./db/db.json');
```